# Vue 3 not rendering components (in Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple blade with a component inside:

```
<section>
    <h1>Carousel</h1>
    <carousel :slides="@json($data->slides)">
</carousel>
```

The component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <fragment>
        <h1>My component</h1>
        {{ slides }}
    </fragment>
</template>

export default {
    props: [
      'slides'
    ],
    mounted() {
        console.log("mounted")
    }
}
```

And of course I have it in app.js (the path is correct):

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('carousel', require('./components/web/partials/Carousel.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({`
    el: '#app',`
});
```

My webpack.mix.js also contains:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')     .vue()     .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

But when I access the page, I can't see the component. I see just the `<h1>Carousel</h1>` that is in the blade. Also there are no errors in the console, which I find weird. The "ExampleComponent" that is created after vue install was not rendering either (I removed it from app.js).

I'm using:

```
"laravel/ui": "^3.3" 
"vue": "^3.2.26", 
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11" 
"sass": "^1.32.11", 
"sass-loader": "^11.0.1", 
"vue-loader": "^16.2.0"
```

I have been trying to switch between vue versions, also vue-loader versions, I have been scrolling through SO with similar problems but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: Any information in the browser's console window?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no, the console is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference `app.js` in your blade file and add id `app` to html tag:

```
<section id="app">
    <h1>Carousel</h1>
    <carousel :slides="@json($data->slides)"></carousel>
<section>
<script src="{{ mix('css/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- First, in your **app.js**, it's how Vue2 init but not Vue3

```js
// vue2 way
new Vue({`
    el: '#app',`
});

// vue3 way
Vue.createApp(...).mount('#app')
```

See how Vue3 init via the [hello-word of Vue3](https://vuejs.org/examples/#hello-world).

- Second, there is no `fragment` in Vue3 built-in-components.

Read the [document](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html) for more details about built-in-components.

In Vue3, you can write a multiple roots component without `<fragment>` directly

```
<template>
    <h1>My component</h1>
    {{ slides }}
</template>
```